# Make css3 animations off in just opera browser

Tags: css, opera, css-animations

How can i turn all css3 animations off in just Opera browser ?

I  don't want to pickup them completly , just want to turn it off in opera.

Comment: Maybe you can give css classes from codebehind(programmatically) and check for browser from there? There should be some commmands for that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be looking at targeting just the opera browser, this is done with a prefix:

```
-o-transition: none;
```

So targeting a specific element would have the following:

```
a {
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: none;
transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

But your transition might be different without looking at a fiddle of your html and css.

Answer (score 0):

At least, i used this code:

```
 noindex:-o-prefocus, * {
  animation : none !important;
        -o-animation : none !important;
}
```

and problem is fixed.